# Determine SSID of an ethernet connection in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, networking, terminal, raspberry-pi

I have connected a raspberry-pi ubuntu device through an ethernet cable to my university's internet but since the university has multiple networks, I am not sure which network it is connected to. Moreover, I found solutions to determine the SSID on wireless connections but those solutions didn't comply with ethernet connections.

How can I find the ssid on my raspberry-py from terminal?

Comment: SSID is a 802.11 extension that only applies to wireless. So, you can't.

Comment: The question doesn't ask anything meaningful. SSID is the "Service Set ID", essentially the name of a *wireless* network. An ethernet doesn't have the same concept. *Perhaps* you could deduce something from a hostname assigned from DHCP, e.g. if you get host17.dorm.university.edu then you might be on the "dorm" network. What are you actually trying to do? If it is something like "can I connect to supercomputer.university.edu?" then just attempt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SSID is a property that is specific to Wi-Fi networks only - a wired ethernet network does not have one.

You could use `tcpdump` to listen for broadcasts and any other background traffic in the cable to determine the IP addresses in use on the network, with something like (assuming your network interface is `eno1`:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eno1 -s0 -Knv
```

This command will output information of any incoming network packet it will see on the wire. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> once you've seen enough. The source addresses of packets you may see may allow you to identify the network segment you're connected to.

Many enterprise-grade network switches may also periodically output discovery protocol packets on each of their ports, carrying the identification of the switch and port and optionally various other information useful for network management. LLDP is a vendor-neutral discovery protocol that seems to be increasingly supported by modern enterprise-grade switches from several vendors.

To capture an incoming LLDP packet (and nothing else) using `tcpdump`, you could do something like this:

```
sudo tcpdump -Knv -s0 -i eno1 -c 1 ether proto 0x88cc
```

and wait for a minute or two for the switch to send a LLDP information packet.

If you receive one, `tcpdump` will decode the information blocks in the packet like this:

```
23:52:08.998832 LLDP, length 131
        Chassis ID TLV (1), length 7
          Subtype MAC address (4): 11:22:33:44:55:66     <- MAC address of the switch
        Port ID TLV (2), length 4
          Subtype Interface Name (5): gi2              <- switch port identifier
        Time to Live TLV (3), length 2: TTL 120s
        Organization specific TLV (127), length 14: OUI IEEE 802.3 Private (0x00120f)
          unknown Subtype (5)
          0x0000:  0012 0f05 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011
        System Name TLV (5), length 12: switch123456    <- switch name configured by network admin
```

The available information may vary between switch models and firmware versions, but it should be useful in figuring out "what's the other end of this network cable connected to?"

If the switches in your network won't send LLDP packets, there are various older vendor-specific discovery protocols you might try. If the switch you're connected to uses one of them that is decodable by `tcpdump`, you will see the decoded results among the output of the first `tcpdump` command I mentioned above.

And of course, you could contact your university's local network support personnel. If you do that, they would surely appreciate if you had all the relevant details ready at hand when doing so, like your apartment/room/whatever number and any identification codes that may be written on the network wall socket you're using.

If you don't have to restrict yourself to passive listening only until you're sure you have connected to the right network, you could also just let the RasPi attempt automatic network configuration by DHCP and see what, if any, results you can get from that.